# What's a good version control system to use to version my whole local filesystem?

Tags: version-control, local, root

I'm in the specific use case of wanting to methodologically document everything significant I do while setting up my new workstation (running Mac OS X Lion).

I would like to version control, in the same repository, files that are at totally different places on my file system, for instance files in `/etc`, `~/`, `/Libraries`, etc.

Some thoughts/details on my requirements:

- This repo will be for personal use only. I'll use a GUI client to browse my settings history.
- I initially wanted to use Git, hosted in one large Github private repository, but as you can't clone subfolders the way you would do it with SVN, I'd have to create symlinks everywhere, which does not seem convenient.
- So, would I be better off setting up a local SVN server and just checking in the files I want, when I want to version them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mercurial, Git, ..., and then simply ignore all the files you don't want to version. Create the repository in the root and track the rest. Like (for Mercurial):

```
$ cd /
$ hg init
$ echo ".*" > .hgignore
$ echo '^(?!(etc|Libraries))' > .hgignore
$ hg add
$ hg commit -m "initial checkin"
```

An alternative is to use more specialized tools such as [etckeeper](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/) that are made for tracking configuration data.

Comment: If, say, I create a git repo on `/`, won't that conflict with subfolders that might be versioned using git as well?

Comment: Ehm, yes. Both Git and Mercurial avoids tracking files inside nested repositories. I can see how tracking `/home` will be a problem with this technique, but it allows you to track config files and liberies.

Comment: Can you explain why tracking `/home`would be a problem?

Comment: You just pointed out that a repository in `/` wont track the content of a, say, `/home/foo/repo` repository. There wont be any such nested repositories in `/etc`, but there could some in `/home`. If the requirement is to version everything including such repos, then Mercurial and Git wont work as is. If you just want to track the setup of a new machine and you don't create other repos, then it'll work fine.

Comment: Even though I added `*`to my `.gitignore` there is a huge performance penalty on my system to `git` at the root. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Hmm, strange: `git status` at the root is instantaneous, but any GUI client (Tower, Github for Mac) freezes on the Status tab (or equivalent) and my monitor tells me it's `git` that's hanging.

I will check whether it's a `git` version problem.

Comment: Do I need to `git add .gitignore` for it to be taken into account?

Comment: There's no need to add `.gitignore`, it takes effect immediately. I have no idea what the graphical Git clients are doing wrong.